# Vuetify2 grid - fill height and grow middle row

Tags: css, grid, height, vuetify.js, fluid-layout

My `<v-content>` is something like this:

```
<v-container>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>ROW 1</v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>ROW 2</v-col>
  </v-row>
  <v-row>
    <v-col>ROW 3</v-col>
  </v-row>
</v-container>
```

To keep the example clean, I didn't include the child elements to `<v-row>`s and replaced them with ROW 1, 2, 3. Row 1 and row 3 have heights around `100px` since they are toolbars with buttons. And the middle row 2 contains a `<textarea>` which should fit all remaining height on screen. Its real height depends on how tall rows 1 and 2 are. If they increase their heights (for example if their child elements are wrapped because the width of the window becomes too small) then the `<textarea>` in row 2 should be smaller in height. But anyway, all of the rows should always fit in the window and the page should never show its vertical scrollbar.

Is it possible to achieve this with Vuetify 2?